# Play Framework - Java: Are @ManyToMany associations resource intensive?

Tags: playframework, many-to-many, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, ebean

**Question**:
Are associations like @OneToMany or @ManyToMany resource intensive memory-wise? i.e. will the Play! server load everything into memory when retrieving the entity containing the respective field?

**Following Scenario:**
Model:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model
{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;        

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(       name = "user_user",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "source_user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "target_user_id"))
    List<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();

    /* 
    Many other fields
    .
    .
    .
    */
}
```

And we call it in a template like so:

```
@(user: User)

@for(friend <- user.friends){
    <div>
       @friend.name
    </div>
}
```

**Question continued:**
Now let's say I happen to have 1000 friends.

- Will each friend in my friends list be loaded into memory?
- And if yes (which seems like the logical conclusion) is it considered 'bad practice' to create @ManyToMany or @OneToMany associations in combination with models that have a larger memory footprint and what would be considered 'best practice'?

Comment: You should get some information about [lazy loading in Ebean](http://www.avaje.org/lazyexample.html).

Comment: If you have 1000 friends, do you really want to show them all on a single page?  This seems like a time to use the standard paging mechanism to show 'next N' friends.